# Toggle("puff") effect with jquery for an area tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hi here is my Code for the map tag

```
echo'<div id="page" style="zoom: 100%">';
$img = '<img src="uploads/'.$row['name'].'" class= "advancedpanorama"   height="500" usemap="testmap" alt="inner" />';
echo $img;
echo '<map id="testmap" name="testmap">'; 
echo '<area class="blue" shape="rect" coords="1583,304,1634,343" href="#" alt="Outside" />';
echo '</map>';
echo '<div>';
```

My Jquery code

```
$(function() {
    $("area").click(function() {
        $("img").toggle("puff");
    });
});
```

I'm not able to access the area tag for the click event any help

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to toggle? `$.toggle()` is just to hide or show an element, the parameters are only for duration and completion callbacks. [Link](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: @BenPearlKahan https://api.jqueryui.com/puff-effect/

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, I stand corrected!

Comment: i have a panorama which has an area i want to all an effect of "puff" to it so that it puffs the image as it goes to the next panorama

Comment: OP - your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/fLc07mt4/1/. The issue is possibly because you define the co-ordinates you define for the `map` is outside the bounds of the `500px` height image. If that's not the case, check the console for errors.

Comment: can u make an example that goes from one image to another by clicking on a specific point of a image that will surely solve my problem

Comment: That is not the issue it is still not working